# pgfplots: 3D surface not filled

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

I'm trying to add a (very simple) 3D plot to a document using `pgfplots`, version 1.16. However, attempting to reproduce the very first example from the manual (page 124),

[image: example from the pgfplots manual]

actually results in this:

[image: failed example]

I'm using the exact code from the manual, i.e.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
% this yields a 3x4 matrix:
\addplot3 [surf] coordinates {
(0,0,0) (1,0,0) (2,0,0) (3,0,0)
(0,1,0) (1,1,0.6) (2,1,0.7) (3,1,0.5)
(0,2,0) (1,2,0.7) (2,2,0.8) (3,2,0.5)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'm using XeLaTeX as my compiler, but the same problem also occurs with LuaLaTeX and plain old latex.

I'm stumped, and would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(As usual, the answer occurred to me literally 30 seconds after asking for help.)

It turns out that the blank lines in the example -- which did not get copied when I copied and pasted the example code from the manual -- are meaningful; in other words,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
% this yields a 3x4 matrix:
\addplot3 [surf] coordinates {
(0,0,0) (1,0,0) (2,0,0) (3,0,0)

(0,1,0) (1,1,0.6) (2,1,0.7) (3,1,0.5)

(0,2,0) (1,2,0.7) (2,2,0.8) (3,2,0.5)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

does indeed yield the desired result. (Just *why* this is is another question, perhaps.)